# How do I restore the recovery partition in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

For some reason, the recovery partition on my computer is gone which means I can't do a restore or a full reinstall of Windows. Here are some screenshots as proof.

Here's one of the "This PC" window:

[image: No Partition in explorer]

If the recovery partition were still functional, we'd see it as a separate hard drive with a capacity of approximately 8 GB

Here's a screenshot of me attempting the reinstall

[image: Can't find recovery]

So does anybody have any idea on how to fix this?

I am asking because I was told in my previous question [VirtualBox won't open. Error code 0x80040154](https://superuser.com/questions/1054690/virtualbox-wont-open-error-code-0x80040154) that I would have to reinstall Windows if I don't have a restore point, which it appears I don't.

Comment: Did it come from your PC manufacturer, if so what is the manufacturer?

Answer (score 1):

If your recovery environment is missing, for what ever reason, you will need to either contact your system vendor/manufacturer (such as Dell, HP, Toshiba, etc.) to acquire a copy of restoration media which is the preferred method, this may or may not reinstall your recovery environment but it will definitely allow you to re-install Windows that was originally shipped with your PC. An alternative would be to use [Microsoft's Media Creation Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media) although at the time of this answer attempting to download it is resulting in a 404 - Not found error, and it appears Microsoft has removed it in favor of Windows 10. Another alternative would be download and burn the full [Microsoft ISO file to disk for Windows 8.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8ISO), which is available on the Microsoft Downloads site.